# Multiple HTML pages into single page

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular, I have two HTML pages and their respective .ts files is it possible to merge two HTML pages into a single HTML page without disturbing .ts files?

Comment: Can you post some code so that we can see what you're aiming to achieve

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-stock-list',
  templateUrl: './stock-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stock-list.component.css']
})
```

You can use app-stock-list selector like this

```
<app-stock-list></app-stock-list>
```

You can add this to the html page you want

Comment: I have used it to merge two pages but data flow is not working properly